# PHP - How to save a simple session?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to save a value (0 or 1) in a session in PHP. I have my session_start() commands at the top but I cannot seem to get it working - it does return the saved number - it keeps returning 0 as in not saving the info - am I resetting something?

**index.php**

```
<?php

# session vars
session_start();
$session_id = session_id();

# set the session 
$sliderNumber=$_SESSION["CurrentSliderPosition"];

# check session
if($sliderNumber=="" || $sliderNumber=="0"){
    echo ' you are saved 0';
} else {
    echo ' saved your session is 1 - even though you have been on other pages';
}

<a href="make-session.php?slidePositionId=1">make 1 the session number</a><br />
<a href="make-session.php?slidePositionId=2">make 2 the session number</a><br />

?>
```

**make-session.php**

```
<?php
# get session number
$sliderNumber=$_REQUEST["slidePositionId"];

# session checker
if($sliderNumber=="0" || $sliderNumber==""){
    $_SESSION["CurrentSliderPosition"]=0;
} else {
    $_SESSION["CurrentSliderPosition"]=$sliderNumber;
}

 //echo $_SESSION["CurrentSliderPosition"];

 # redirect with our saved session
 header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Add `session_start()` in your make-session.php (at the top) and tell me if that helps.

Comment: What does this have to do with the jQuery plugin?

Comment: Sorry @GGG (cool name), removed that remark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `make-session.php` page doesn't have a `session_start();`, and it should.

Comment: Do I need it on every page? As I Thought SESSION is saved in MEMORY.

Comment: You need it on every page you want to read a session or write to a session.

Comment: Every script that runs and uses sessions has to call start_session. I'm not really sure why you're doing `$session_id = session_id();`, Id don't really see the need.

Comment: @Nanne I have seen it in Google when searching before posting, lot of people seem to have it.

Comment: Yes you do on every page you use $_SESSION. Here some reading http://www.josephcrawford.com/php-articles/going-deep-inside-php-sessions/

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is saved: the php file needs to actually "load" the session (for lack of a better description) when a script is run. So a new script doesn't have a session. You can compare it with starting a database connection if you like: if you open a new page, you need to open your connection again, or at least load your persistent connection if you've fiddled with that :)

Comment: @khalid : never just randomly copy stuff :). Try to understand what you are doing, read the manual etc: If you think about it, what you're doing is loading the Id in a variable, and then doing nothing with that variable, so there's no need to do it. No real harm either, but still.

Comment: I liked the Database connection reference but I still cannot upvote comments. Sorry :)